# Mac mini 2011-mid and SSD sata 3

Tags: ssd, mac-mini

can someone tell me, will [this ssd](http://www.toshiba.com/us/accessories/Storage/Solid-State-Drives/512GB/HDTS351XZSTA) disc work on my mac mini, since is sata 3? As I know my mac uses sata 2?

But I'm really novice and I have no idea.

Comment: sorry its bugging me, its not *a disc* ;)

Comment: @Jakub don't get it?

Comment: @5er Quite possibly he means that the media is more correctly thought of as an array of NAND chips than a "flat circular plate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will works. It is not a differance, because it is backward compatible.
You can find out here more if you are interested about compatibility [SATA II vs. SATA III](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/270771-32-sata-sata-backwards-compatible)

But one thing you must take in care, that you won't reach speeds of data 3, because your bus only support sata2

Comment: So that means that I won't get out of the disc 500~/500~?

Comment: yes but only the max. speed of sata2 that is 3.0 gbps = 375 MB/s

Comment: Ouch, didn't know that.. thx. I was looking for disc with 500Mb/s rw. I can take a look on cheaper discs. You just save me some money...

Comment: Are you shore that this particular SSD will work? because I heard that some discs don't work with mac.

Comment: Why does not work?? It will works, because it is a standard 2.5 inch same size that you have your HDD in.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think it's SATA2. According to everything I read, the mid-2011 Mini is SATA3

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.5-mid-2011-specs.html

There are considerations related to garbage collection related to the SSD controller. The safest choice is a OWC Mercury from macsales.com since they are intended for Macs. Others may require installing a 3rd-party TRIM enabling utility.

Comment: I'm not sure. I was only assuming. If that's true, it's great.. I will check that out...